# Why is there a dummy union member in some implementations of std::optional?

Tags: c++, c++17, option-type, unions

Both libstdc++ (GNU) and libc++ (LLVM) implement `std::optional` value storage using a union and both of them include a dummy member.

GNU implementation:

```
using _Stored_type = remove_const_t<_Tp>;
struct _Empty_byte { };
union {
    _Empty_byte _M_empty;
    _Stored_type _M_payload;
};
```

LLVM implementation:

```
union
{
    char __null_state_;
    value_type __val_;
};
```

My question is: Why do we need these `_M_empty`/`__null_state_` members? Is there something wrong with a single-member union?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Single member union creates all sorts of problem when trying to be default constructible and be constexpr compatible.

Consider this code:

```
struct nontrivial {
    constexpr nontrivial(int o) : u{o} {}
    int u;
};

union storage {
    nontrivial nt;
};

struct optional {
    storage s;
};

constexpr auto run() -> int {
    optional o;
    return o.s.nt.u;
}

int main() {
    constexpr int t = run();
}
```

This is ill formed because `optional` has a deleted constructor.

Then a simple fix would be to add a constructor that initialize no union member:

```
union storage {
    constexpr storage() {} // standard says no
    nontrivial nt;
};
```

But it won't work. Constexpr unions must have at least one active member. It cannot be an empty union. To workaround this limitation, a dummy member is added. This makes `std::optional` useable in constexpr context.

(Thanks @Barry!) From [[dcl.constexpr]/4](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.dcl#dcl.constexpr-4.1) (emphasis mine):

> The definition of a constexpr constructor whose function-body is not = delete shall additionally satisfy the following requirements:
>
> - **if the class is a union having variant members ([class.union]), exactly one of them shall be initialized;**
> - if the class is a union-like class, but is not a union, for each of its anonymous union members having variant members, exactly one of them shall be initialized;
> - for a non-delegating constructor, every constructor selected to initialize non-static data members and base class subobjects shall be a constexpr constructor;
> - for a delegating constructor, the target constructor shall be a constexpr constructor.

Comment: For those hunting for the standard quote: http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.dcl#dcl.constexpr-4.1

Comment: @TedLyngmo, which version? Tried on 7.4.0 - got an error.

Comment: @r3musn0x 9.1.1. I don't think 7.4.0 implements [LWG 2900](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/libstdc%2B%2B/2017-03/msg00109.html).

Comment: @TedLyngmo, it looks to me that LWG 2900 is only related to the library implementation of optional, so I don't really see the connection... Anyway look [here](https://godbolt.org/z/EVyLfL) - an error! :)

Comment: @r3musn0x You are probably correct. Here's a [comparison](https://godbolt.org/z/0eaNDg) between g++ and clang++ and also a bugreport that seems to be connected to this: [bugzilla #886581](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=86581) It seems to hit my example when templates are involved, but in the bugreport they've managed to trigger the bug without templates.